# How to use Python thread with one argument function?

Tags: python, multithreading

I create a main function below with two argument function inside `Thread`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define ports
    ports_for_server_connection=[10003, 10004, 10005, 10006]
    for port_number in ports_for_server_connection:
        # Open multi thread sockets so that each will respond independently
        t = Thread(target=openServer, args=(port_number, 1))
        t.start()
```

However, I want to create that function with only one argument. When I tried to implement it with one argument(`args=(port_number, 1)`) I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: openServer() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

How can I use thread with only one argument function?

Thanks,

Comment: show `openServer` function definition

Comment: 'def openServer(port, listen_on):'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it only one argument:

```
t = Thread(target=openServer, args=(port_number,))
```

The trick bit is that `(x,)` is a tuple of length one those first item is `x`. If this is too hard just use a list:

```
t = Thread(target=openServer, args=[port_number])
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggest and it works well. Thanks.